# How to show only selected number of elements in array?

Tags: javascript

I developed a party-game just for fun, and can't solve this problem. So, at first I ask user "How many clothes you want to see?". I set that data to local storage, and use on other page. So my problem is: I want to show only user selected number of elements in array (I'm so sorry for my bad english, I really need your help). Here are my codes:

index.html

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="small-container">
        <p id="text">How many clothes you want to choose ?</p>
        <input type="number" placeholder="1 to 6" id="count" />
      </div>
      <button id="btn">Start</button>
</div>
```

script1.js

```
window.onload = function() {
        var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        var count = document.getElementById("count");
        btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
          document.location.href = "random.html";
          localStorage.setItem("count", count.value);
        });
};
```

game.html

```
<div class="small-container">
        <p id="text">Your random clothes: </p>
        <img id="img" />
</div>
```

script2.js

```
    var options = [
          "T-Shirt",
          "Singlet",
          "Underwear",
          "Socks",
          "Shorts",
          "Shoes"
        ];
        var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        var text = document.getElementById("text");
        var img = document.getElementById("img");
        btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
          var count = localStorage.getItem("count");

          var randomChoice = options.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length), 1);
          btn.innerHTML = "Shuffle";
          text.innerHTML = randomChoice;
          img.setAttribute("src", `img/${randomChoice}.png`);

          if (randomChoice >= options.length) {
            text.innerHTML = "End of game :)";
            btn.innerHTML = "Start again";
            img.removeAttribute("src");
            btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
              // document.location.href = "intro.html";
              document.location.href = "random.html";
            });
          }
        });
      };
```

So every time user clicks the button, clothes are changing. For example, if user was chosen 4 as count, I want to show him/her only 4 clothes, and they must see before every click just one image on their pages.

Comment: Wait so basically the user keeps pressing "Shuffle" until the random picks the last element in the array and then the game is over? You want to restrain the number of items used in the game taking the first N or taking N random items from the list?

Comment: @Onheiron user keeps pressing "Shuffle" button until that time, he sees number of elements was chosen by him. For example, if he enters 3, I choose 3 random elements from array, and at each click user sees one of them. When 3 elements all are shown, the game ends

Comment: @Onheiron yes, I want to take N random items form the list

Comment: but `randomChoice` is an element of the array, not the number of picks the user made, how can `randomChoice >= options.length` valuate correctly?

Comment: @Onheiron that's why I need your help, my dear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood ur question correctly, your issue was that you didnt know how to stop the game once the good amount of clothes has been shown

Here is a solution

```
        btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
          var count = localStorage.getItem("count");
          localStorage.setItem("count", count-1); //decreasing the value of count because one clothe is about to be shown on screen
          if (count == 0) { //if count is at 0, that means game is over
                text.innerHTML = "End of game :)";
                btn.innerHTML = "Start again";
                img.removeAttribute("src");
                btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
                  // document.location.href = "intro.html";
                  document.location.href = "random.html";
                });
          }

          else{ //we show a new cloth
              var randomChoice = options.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length), 1);
              btn.innerHTML = "Shuffle";
              text.innerHTML = randomChoice;
              img.setAttribute("src", `img/${randomChoice}.png`);
          }
        });
```

But with that code its still possible that the same cloth is picked several times.
To avoid that, while keeping the code in pure javascript, I guess you could use "hidden" inputs to store the clothes that have been shown, or other localStorage variables.